# A text inside a class should check for a text in another class and if it matches change the css style of the first text

Tags: jquery

This is my second question in stackoverflow and please excuse me for any mistakes..now my question is...
Assume there are two elements with two classes.

first className is **topics**

```
<p class="topics">9-3-5-8</p>
```

second className is **complete** inside a span tag

```
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=gst_in_india_-_an_introduction"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">6 </span>GST IN INDIA - AN INTRODUCTION</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=taxable_event_-_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">5 </span>TAXABLE EVENT - SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=charge_of_gst"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">4 </span>CHARGE OF GST</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=exemptions_from_gst"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">3 </span>EXEMPTIONS FROM GST</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=_place_of_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">1 </span> PLACE OF SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=time_of_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">2 </span>TIME OF SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=value_of_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">7 </span>VALUE OF SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=input_tax_credit"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">8 </span>INPUT TAX CREDIT</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=registration"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">9 </span>REGISTRATION</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=_tax_invoice,_credit_and_debit_notes"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">10 </span> TAX INVOICE, CREDIT AND DEBIT NOTES</p></a>
```

Now each **text** inside the span element with a class name **complete** should read the text inside the **topics class** for example as 5 is in 9-5-3-8 now span tag css color value should be changed...I am facing trouble with this issue any help is highly appreciated..

[screenshot shot of current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nzKS.png)

[screenshot of required page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rv3h.png)

Comment: Have you any code for it?

Comment: No i did not write any jquery code..i tried but none worked@Mohammad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not post your attempt code,I provide a solution using `each()` to do it

Notice: we need to use `$.trim()` to remove the duplicate space

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
  var topics = $.trim($(".topics").text()).split("-");
  $(".complete").each(function(index,element){
     var val = $.trim($(element).text());
     if($.inArray(val,topics) >-1){
       $(element).parent().css("color","red");
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="topics">9-3-5-8-17</p>

<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=gst_in_india_-_an_introduction"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">6 </span>GST IN INDIA - AN INTRODUCTION</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=taxable_event_-_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">5 </span>TAXABLE EVENT - SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=charge_of_gst"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">4 </span>CHARGE OF GST</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=exemptions_from_gst"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">3 </span>EXEMPTIONS FROM GST</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=_place_of_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">1 </span> PLACE OF SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=time_of_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">2 </span>TIME OF SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=value_of_supply"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">7 </span>VALUE OF SUPPLY</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=input_tax_credit"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">8 </span>INPUT TAX CREDIT</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=registration"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">9 </span>REGISTRATION</p></a>            
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=_tax_invoice,_credit_and_debit_notes"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">10 </span> TAX INVOICE, CREDIT AND DEBIT NOTES</p></a>
<a  href="mychapter.php?chapter=_tax_invoice,_credit_and_debit_notes"><p class="chapters"><span  class="complete">17 </span>Taiwan Next</p></a>
```

Comment: everything working fine with single numbers but when the number is 9-3-5-8-17- instead of selecting 17 it is selecting 1 and 7...please help with this issue @Iucumt

Comment: @vamshig Then do not use `indexOf()`,you can make `topics` as arrays,and check if the value in the array or not

Comment: i have no idea how to do that...could you help @Iucumt

Comment: accepted bro...thank you for sharing your knowledge..:) @Iucumt